# Do I need to quit all drivers separately while automating app using appium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

I have initialized a driver in "X" class and made a getDriver method there.
In "Y" class I am creating a reference variable and assigning getDriver() method to it.
now in after hook im doing X.getDriver().quit. will it quit all the drivers or I need to quit class "Y's" driver too?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium `X.getDriver().quit` would close all the open instances of browser opened by **webdriver**.

In case you are looking to **close** just single instance you may wanna opt for `.close` not `.quit`